Mapping eventNum and eventType for GameMaker's .yy files when deleting event files
I'm developing a linter for GML, and I'm working on a function to remove unnecessary files. When deleting event files, GameMaker doesn't automatically remove lines from the corresponding .yy file. I haven't found any documentation on eventNum and eventType. Does anyone have data for mapping these values (e.g., 'Draw_0': (0, 0) or 'Draw_73': (73, 8))? Manually creating this mapping is time-consuming, and any help would be appreciated!

Late answer, but it's less work than you might think! The file name structure is eventTypeName + "_" + eventNumber + ".gml", and if it's a collision event, object name takes place of eventNumber.
The event types are as following as of GM2024:
linkType(0, "Create");
linkType(1, "Destroy");
linkType(2, "Alarm");
linkType(3, "Step");
linkType(4, "Collision");
linkType(5, "Keyboard");
linkType(6, "Mouse");
linkType(7, "Other");
linkType(8, "Draw");
linkType(9, "KeyPress");
linkType(10, "KeyRelease");
linkType(12, "CleanUp");
linkType(13, "Gesture");

And if you need to translate numeric eventType-eventNumber, I mapped most of those for GMEdit at one point.
